# Spell Checker : Ternary Search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, spell-checking, ternary-search-tree

i have made a spell checker code using Ternary search tree. Can anybody tell me how to find the next possible word in TST.
for example if i want to search if i search a word "Manly" in spell checker and the word is not present in TST, so the output it gives like
DO YOU MEAN:
"Man"
"Mango"
.
.means possible near words

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented my own spell checker but instead of a simple ternary trie I am using a ternary dag as Peter Kankowski suggests [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32089/Using-Ternary-DAGs-for-Spelling-Correction).  You can look at my [blog](http://pomlex.blogspot.gr/2014/10/blog-post.html) for some details and how I did it. Its in Greek, but you can get an idea.

Edit:

Ok, you are right.
The basic idea is to use a pre-created list of candidates for a given edit distance ( a value of 2 for me is ok ).   To reduce the size of the list one can use wildcard characters.
Such a list, of course, can be constructed in different ways.  I prefer for / while loops like this ( e.g. for candidates of two substitutions )

```
void Substitute2( vector<wchar_t*>& v, const wstring& w )
{
    size_t len = w.size();
    if ( len < 2 )
        return;
    size_t p1 = 0, p2 = 1;
    while ( p1 < len ) {
        p2 = p1 + 1;
        while ( p2 < len ) {
            wchar_t* chars = new wchar_t[ len + 1 ];
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
                if ( i != p1 && i != p2 ) {
                    chars[ i ] = w[ i ];
                }
            }
            chars[ p1 ] = '?';
            chars[ p2 ] = '?';
            chars[ len ] = '\0';
            v.push_back( chars );
            p2++;
        }
        p1++;
    }
}
```

After having prepared the candidates list, a simple search in a ternary dag for each item in the list will give us the suggestions for that misspelled word.

```
void Search( FileNode* pDict, FileNode* pNode, const wchar_t* Word, wstring Sug, set<wstring>& List )
{
    if ( IsNullLink( pNode, pDict ) )
        return;
    if ( *Word == '?' ) {
        Search( pDict, GetLo( pNode, pDict ), Word, Sug, List );
        Search( pDict, GetEq( pNode, pDict ), Word + 1, Sug + pNode->Char, List );
        Search( pDict, GetHi( pNode, pDict ), Word, Sug, List );
    } else {
        if ( *Word < pNode->Char ) {
            Search( pDict, GetLo( pNode, pDict ), Word, Sug, List );
        } else if ( *Word > pNode->Char ) {
            Search( pDict, GetHi( pNode, pDict ), Word, Sug, List );
        } else {
            if ( pNode->Char == '\0' )
            {
                List.insert( Sug );
            }
            if ( *Word != '\0' ) {
                Search( pDict, GetEq( pNode, pDict ), Word + 1, Sug + pNode->Char, List );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The dictionary is a compiled (file based) ternary dag

Comment: it is great ,a lot to learn , which compiler you are using which is showing suggested words. and Ternary dag is quiet interesting ,have you shared your code on your blog.

Comment: The most important portions of the code are publicly available.
I am using Microsoft's VS 2012 compiler.

Comment: Sorry, but link-only answers are not good on Stackoverflow. Please include the code in your answer. Or pseudocode and schemes, if that is enough to explain an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The search for the word in your TST will terminate at a specific location in the tree. From this point, you can simply go up one level in the tree until you hit a level where there is more than just the child you came from.

On that level, you can simply choose the other possible paths and return those words.

Comment: there are three pointers in TST..left,equal and right if the word is not matches for searching a word it goes to the leaf in a tree as in BST so how to implement can you clarify more

Comment: A search in a TST containing strings can track its path (unless you only want to know whether your string is contained or not in the TST). If you track your path, then you have 4 options: left, equal, right and up (go where you came from). This is what I'm referring to when I said 'go up one level in the tree'.

Comment: can you please modify the code here i need for my college project urgently                                                     http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ternary-search-tree/